# Is there a way sort eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors in pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, torch

Is there a way to sort a matrix based on another matrix or vector in pytorch? Given eigenvalues and eigenvectors as shown below:

```
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = torch.eig(matrix,eigenvectors=True) #compute the eigenvalues & vectors

sortedEig, indices=torch.sort(w, dim=1, descending=True)
eigenvectors_sorted = lamb.gather(dim=1, index=indices)
```

I need to sort eigenvectors by decreasing eigenvalues. The code above shows what I have tried out. However the output, **eigenvectors_sorted** is a **N x 2 tensor** instead of **N x N tensor**  which **eigenvectors** actually is.

Note that in pytorch, eigenvalues is a **N x 2 tensor**.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, eigenvalues are `Nx2` because they are _complex_ numbers. If you want to sort them you'll need to decide how to compare them first. You might want to look at their absolute values for comparison. Then you can index the eigenvectors based on the sorted indices.

Comment: OK! Since the first element/column of the eigenvalue tensor is the real part and the second element is the imaginary part, is it safe to use/take just the first element(real part) for sorting? Or do I need to combine them? If yes, is there a way to combine them?